# .load() seems to always use request.POST

Tags: jquery

I am trying to partial load a page with jquery.

I don't understand why `row.load()` always sends a request.POST when I click on the link, where it should really have sent a request.GET. Is there anything I have overlooked?

**html:**

```
<a class="row_edit" href="/sales_item/edit/{{ item.id }}" title="{% trans 'Edit' %}"><i class="icon-pencil"> </i></a>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".row_edit").click(row_edit);
});

function row_edit() {
    // e.g. url = '/sales_item/edit/8' 
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var row = $(this).closest('tr')
    row.load(
        url + "/",
        null,
        function () {
            $("#save-form").submit(row_save); 
        }
    );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any data being passed, by GET *or* POST.

Comment: If you aren't passing data, don't pass data. `$(el).load(url,successhandler)`

Comment: @Kevin, this is the answer. Thank you. Even null counts as data...weird

Comment: jQuery loves overloading methods. In this particular case, `null` isn't a function, and it isn't `undefined`... so their implementation takes this to mean object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) docs:

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise,
>   GET is assumed.

Just omit the `null` arg.

Comment: I've always found that particular bit of documentation confusing, personally.

Comment: The doc syntax is `.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )`... with the "data" option in brackets, meaning it's completely optional.

Comment: I know it's optional and I know you have to omit it to get it to use GET, but I think their way of phrasing it is confusing. If not passed as an object, than how? As far as I can tell, then answer is "not at all" and then you pass the information for GET through the URL.

Comment: In javascript, `undefined` is not the same as `null`.

Comment: I knew that also, but I suppose the distinction is relevant here because `undefined` is not an object?

Comment: lolz... upgrade jQuery https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/b292c4c2df673d17d8c720e13d4d81ecae4ec499

Answer (score 0):

To pass information by GET through `.load()`, just append the data to the URL as you usually would (`url?key=value&key2=value2` etc). Your example doesn't really indicate what information that would be, though, or I'd give you an example.